# .net CSV file stream to browser loosing characters on production server

Tags: c#, browser, stream, download

I've got basic functionality to stream a file to the browser which invokes a "Save As". The output is dynamically generated and stored within a string and not a file saved on the server.

See code below.

```
string output = GenerateCSVDdata;
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"test.csv\");
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble());
Response.Write(output);
Response.End();
```

Now, on my development server, the CSV fully downloads. On the production server, the last few characters on end are cut off. The larger the CSV, the more characters are missing. I've tried so many different things like Response.Flush etc but nothing can fix it. The only thing I can do is throw a load of empty chars on the end in hope nothing gets cut.

Is there something quite wrong with this method of streaming a file download without actually saving the file to disk?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it worked for me.

```
    void DownloadFile(string filename)
    {
            //string filename = "c:\\temp\\test.csv";
            byte[] contents = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);

            Response.Clear();
            Response.ClearHeaders();

            Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}\"", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filename)));
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "binary/octet-stream");
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-length", contents.Length.ToString());


            Response.BinaryWrite(contents);
            if (Response.IsClientConnected)                
                Response.Flush();

    }
```

Regards.

Comment: Looks like BinaryWrite fixed it. Would you know why that could be?

Comment: Maybe your string was not in the same encoding as the promised encoding? what does 'Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble());' do?

Comment: I read it on another thread and if I understand it correctly, it helps the decoder determine the byte order. Response.Charset and other methods weren't working.

Comment: Can you determine if there is a difference in the count for the .csv file?

Comment: I couldn't. Originally I was doing a content length on string instead of a byte array. Wonder if that makes a diff.

Answer (score 1):

Can you determine if there is a difference in the byte count for the .csv file you are using?

```
byte[] defaultEncodingBytes = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(defaultEncodingFileContents);
byte[] UTF8EncodingBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(defaultEncodingFileContents);
```

Comment: Ah yes, there are differences. UTF8 encoding is larger. Explains it as the length must have been too short for the content length. Thanks